# Menu always hidden to three dots instead of shown in action bar

Tags: android

I have an activity with navigation drawer. The activity contain a view pager that hold 3 fragment. I've inflate the menu successfully. But, instead of showing the icon in action bar, it's hidden in three dots.

I've menu code below :

**home_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView">
    </item>
</menu>
```

**onCreateOptionsMenu() code :**

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val inflater = MenuInflater(this)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu)

    val searchItem: MenuItem? = menu!!.findItem(R.id.search_menu)
    searchItem?.let {
        it.actionView?.let {
            val searchView: SearchView = it as SearchView
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

What's wrong ?

Is another menu file will affected to that menu ?

Here's another menu files :

**activity_home_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/admin_menu"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="Admin Menu">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/manage_user"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_group_gray_24dp"
                android:title="Manage User" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/manage_schedule"
                android:icon="@drawable/baseline_calendar_today_24"
                android:title="Manage Schedule" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_edit_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_edit_24"
            android:title="Edit Profile" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_exit_to_app_24"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

**bottom_navigation_drawer_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_user_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
        android:title="Search User"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/schedule_request_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_inbox_24"
        android:title="Request"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: show your `OnCreateMenu()` code

Comment: okay, i've show my onCreateOptionsMenu() code @NullPointerException

Comment: Have you set `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside onCreateView of your fragment ?

Comment: Yes, I do @RakhiDhavale

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to show a menu icon then try this.**

you should add `showAsAction` attribute to `always` or `ifRoom`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_filter"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: I had tried it. And it gives and error that i should change ```android:showAsAction``` to ```app:showAsAction```